# Logstash translate not working in place

Tags: logstash

The following `translate` filter does not seem to work. In the logstash output I still see `dport` entries with the value `-`. However, if I uncomment the destination option, the filter works as expected, generating a `test` field with value `-1` when appropriate. Why is the in-place translation not working?

```
translate {
    field => "dport"
    #destination => "test"
    dictionary => ["-", "-1"]
}
```

Some background: I am trying to have all `dport` values as integers, so the field can be indexed correctly by elasticsearch. The field `dport` should contain an integer, however if the field was not initialized the value `-` is logged.

Answer (score 2):

Either my understanding of the documentation is wrong, or this is a [bug](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-translate/issues/11).

In any case, this seems to work:

```
translate {
  field => "dport"
  destination => "dport"
  override => "true"
  dictionary => ["-", "-1"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test this behaviour with the last version of the plugins by adding this test:
`
 describe "implace translation" do

```
let(:config) do
  {
    "field"       => "status",
    "dictionary"  => [ "-", "-1"]
  }
end

let(:event) { LogStash::Event.new("status" => "-") }

it "return the exact translation" do
  subject.register
  subject.filter(event)
  expect(event["translation"]).to eq("-1")
end
```

and everything works as expected. Keep in mind the default field for a translation is the translation field, not sure if this might be the source of your issue.